# xsl and xpath : search for a node inside a node, and return the value of an attribute in the found node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the below xml :

```
<w:style w:styleId="John">
  <w:name w:val="Peter" />
</w:style>
```

So basically, having the value of "Peter", I would like to get the value of "John" (which I would not know at that moment). There will be a lot of "w:style" nodes in my xml.

How do I get the value of  "John" string returned to me using xslt (and xpath) 1.0 (preferably calling a named template to return the value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic XPath expression that will extract what you need is

```
//w:style[w:name/@w:val = 'Peter']/@w:styleId
```

but as you've tagged your question "XSLT" and you say you have many of these nodes you might be better off using a key

```
<xsl:key name="nameByVal" match="w:name" use="@w:val" />
```

and then you can more efficiently query using

```
key('nameByVal', 'Peter')/../@w:styleId
```

or if the `w:name` might be nested inside other elements rather than a direct child of `w:style` then

```
key('nameByVal', 'Peter')/ancestor::w:style/@w:styleId
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you mean <xsl:key name="nameByVal" match="w:name" use="@w:val" />   right?  ("select" is to be replaced by "match")

Comment: @HarveyDarvey well spotted. That'll teach me to type things out from memory rather than testing them first.